# Deleting elements from doubly bounded pointer list

Tags: c++, pointers

I am working on a project where I create a double bounded pointer list, delete several elements, and still be able to read off the list. I have a double bounded pointer list, but am having trouble deleting elements and keeping the list double bounded. This then causes issues when trying to print the list.
Below is the IF statement I've placed in a while loop to help delete unwanted elements. I keep getting a segmentation fault (core dumped).

```
if ((black2 != black)||(white2 != white)) {
        dump = help;
        help = help ->next;
        dump -> before = temp;
        temp -> next = help;
        help ->before = temp;
        delete dump; 
    }//if
    else { temp = help;
           help = help->next;
           help ->before = temp; }//else
```

Comment: Is there any reason for not using [`deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque)?

Comment: Have you consulted examples of a doubly *linked* list?  There are many, including some on StackOverflow.

Comment: You will need to provide more context in your code for people to help you better.

Comment: Do you mean "logic error"?  You would get a specific compiler message if there were an error in syntax.

Answer (score 0):

To maintain properly the doubly linked list you should do something like :

```
void remove(X *elt) {
    X* before = elt->before;
    X* after = elt->next;
    if (before != NULL) { // assuming first element points to NULL
        before->next = after;
    }
    else {
        first = after; // assuming first is a pointer to first element of list
    }
    if (after != NULL) { // assuming last element points to NULL
        after->before = before;
    }
    else {
        last = before; // assuming last is a pointer to last element
    }
    delete elt;
}
```

That way, you ensure that elements around current correctly point to each other dealing with special cases of removing first or last element.

But you already have a `std::list` template in Standard Template Library

Answer (score 0):

One logical issue in your code is the line `dump->before = temp`.
What this does is that it sets the previous node pointer of `dump` to `temp`, as opposed to defining `temp` as the previous node.

The correct line should read `temp = dump->before`

PS: Your code is correct assuming that the node you are deleting isn't the first or last node (and you haven't padded with dummy nodes). You should introduce checks for these cases if required.